# Play framework autotest doesn't run

Tags: testing, playframework

Play framework autotest doesn't run.
After messages

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000
~
~ Go to http://localhost:9000/@tests to run the tests
~
```

nothing happens.

but **play test** works fine.

Does anyone have any idea about this problem?
Thank you in advance!

**I have found the problem.**
I deleted file log4j.properties and now auto-test works fine.